# Dynamic font size in html

Tags: html

Give some data from server like (width,height box)and text.
in html I should create box(or border) and put my text on it.
because of the width and height is different and I want my text fill all box.
how can i set dynamically font size that all words put in box.

Comment: You need to do Javascript calculations for that, CSS cannot do this.

Comment: @connexo - Wrong. You can use rem sizing, which is based on the previous container font size although usually used on the `<html>` tag itself

Comment: @ggdx That will not address the problem OP stated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Comment: @connexo how can i handle with javascript?